# How to couple Fortran77 and Fortran90 applications? MPI, PVM or another way?

Tags: fortran, mpi, coupling, pvm

I need to couple two codes ( one is in Fortran77 and the other in Fortran90 ) which have to be controlled by a daemon and being able to pass information between them.

I have been searching and two possible options are PVM or MPI. The problem is that I need to compile them separately, any ideas?

Comment: ideas about what?

Comment: In addition they are alternatives which should be examined. for instance a single executable instead of two, or the use of sockets instead of PVM or MPI.

Comment: In case you are positing that a different compiler should be used for "F77" code, such an idea probably makes no sense here, as most current compilers support F77 with reasonable extensions as well as F90/2003+.

Answer (score 2):

MPI is well adapted to the SPMD paradigm (Single Program / Multiple data). If you want to couple 2 different binaries, MPI is probably not the best tool. Inter-process communication is more like what you want to do. In Linux, if you stay on the same machine, you can use named pipes (see `man mkfifo`) and you can transfer your data using Fortran I/O calls. Another possibility if you want to communicate between different machines is to use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) for example, and there exists a [Fortran binding](https://github.com/zeromq/f77_zmq).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using POSIX sockets - but you will need to do data serialization/deserialization and it is pretty slow in general. So I would not recommend using sockets.

Technically MPI can work. If you can use MPI 2.0 compliant library then you can use the client-server mechanism implemented there. Look at the documentation for [MPI_Open_port](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Open_port.html) and [MPI_Comm_connect](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Comm_connect.html). The first one will give you the port name that you will need to pass this name to the client somehow. One option is to use [name publishing](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node104.htm) but it may not work with any MPI library. The other option is to share it using some other mechanism (socket connection, file system or anything else).

But, in fact, I still do not see the reason why you should compile these two apps separately (unless there is a licensing issue) - you can just compile them into one package (I anticipate some code change but it is minor) and then run them as one app.